# Inserting data using Gridview, only first row is entered, subsequent rows ignored

Tags: stored-procedures, c#

I have a Gridview in my asp.net site that collect user entries and then submits those entries for insertion to my SQL table. Currently this process works but it will only insert data from the first Gridview row, subsequent rows are seemingly ignored. Any help is greatly appreciated!! :)

Here is my C# code begin my button click:

```
foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "spCreateOrder";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@track_num", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pckg_num", TextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manuf_name", g1.Cells[0].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model_name", g1.Cells[1].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", g1.Cells[2].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", g1.Cells[3].Text);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

And here is my stored procedure "spCreateOrder":

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateOrder]

@customer_id INT,
@track_num NVARCHAR(50),
@pckg_num NUMERIC,
@manuf_name NVARCHAR(50),
@model_name NVARCHAR(50),
@qty NUMERIC,
@notes NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customer_id=@customer_id AND track_num=@track_num)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @NewOrder TABLE (order_id INT);

        INSERT INTO Orders
            (customer_id, track_num, pckg_num)
        OUTPUT
            inserted.order_id INTO @NewOrder
        VALUES
            (@customer_id, @track_num, @pckg_num);

        INSERT INTO Items
            (manuf, model, qty, notes, order_id)
        SELECT
            @manuf_name, @model_name, @qty, @notes, order_id
        FROM @NewOrder;

    END
    ELSE

        INSERT INTO Items
            (manuf, model, qty, notes, order_id)
        SELECT
            @manuf_name, @model_name, @qty, @notes, order_id
        FROM @NewOrder;

END
```

Comment: It's been a hot minute since I was in the .NET world, but does the redirect stop the page execution (and the loop)?

Comment: I tried to run it without the redirect and got the same result so I don't think that is the issue. Thanks!

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` in a ASP.NET? It is a `System.Windows.Form` function. And I think so `Response.Redirect()` is not in the correct place. Have you checked the SP is properly working?

Comment: I thought it was but after further testing it looks like it's not working correctly. I'm just really having a hard time with this, I almost wonder if I'm choosing the most difficult method of doing something fairly simple. New to asp.net and SQL so learning as I go.. Thinking I may need to post another question and get some ideas on how to proceed. My plan doesn't seem to be working. :)

Comment: BTW, there is a missing `@` here `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_id", TextBox1.Text);`

Comment: Thank you! Corrected that and reevaluated by SP but still no luck. SP does work after fixing parameter issue but any gridview rows besides row 1 are seemingly ignored. :(

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point and debugging? You should be able to go line by line and see whether the loop is failing to execute, or if it is a problem with the values themselves.

Comment: Would I get errors with a breakpoint that I wouldn't get using normal debugging? I dont get any C# errors.

Comment: After attempting breakpoint debugging it appears that the foreach loop isn't working. It doesn't give me any error but it didn't loop through the gridview rows when I used step into to look at the code line by line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a [Table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) on your stored procedure fill that in code and send the whole table and merge it. Hell of a lot more efficient than a row-by-row and just as easy to [implement](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters).

As to your error, did you test with profiler what SQL actually get send to the server?